# Prove convergence in probability given a finite moment condition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Having some trouble with a probability/measure theory proof. I need to show that if for some $s>0$, $E[|X|^s] < \infty$, then :

$a^sP{|X > a|} \rightarrow 0$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$.

Initially, I saw similarities between this and Markov's inequality, which states that $P(|X|>\epsilon) \le E|X|^k/\epsilon^k$ for $\epsilon>0$ and $k>0$. This implies $a^sP{|X > a|} \le a^s\frac{E|X|^k}{\epsilon^k}$, and since the $RHS \rightarrow \infty$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$, this just tells me the RHS is finite, which does not help.

Alternatively I could write out the integral as:

$E[|X|^s = \int_\Omega |X|^s\cdot1(|X| \le a)dP + \int_\Omega |X|^s\cdot1(|X| > a)dP$

but I am not sure where to go from here. Any help to complete the proof appreiciated.

Answer (score 1):

By the dominated convergence theorem,
$$
a^s\mathsf{P}(|X|>a)\le \mathsf{E}[|X|^s 1\{|X|>a\}]\to 0 \quad\text{as}\quad a\to \infty.
$$